# Javascript - React - Arrow Function Usage Understanding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this is coded

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dc2149ec0c63bfc95b71e40c81431e34cfbfeda9/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js#L8

```
const NavLink = ({
  to,
  exact,
  strict,
  activeClassName,
  className,
  activeStyle,
  style,
  isActive: getIsActive,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    path={typeof to === 'object' ? to.pathname : to}
    exact={exact}
    strict={strict}
    children={({ location, match }) => {
      const isActive = !!(getIsActive ? getIsActive(match, location) : match)

      return (
        <Link
          to={to}
          className={isActive ? [ activeClassName, className ].join(' ') : className}
          style={isActive ? { ...style, ...activeStyle } : style}
          {...rest}
        />
      )
    }}
  />
)
```

What's going on here? Is this defining a function that returned a JSX element? The only thing that is throwing me is the JSX element being wrapped in parentheses `()`

What is going on in the first part where there is `isActive: getIsActive`?

I was looking at http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies and couldn't find a direct example.

I was trying to figure out how to use the `isActive` method of `router` and couldn't parse this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isActive: getIsActive` - this is aliasing of `isActive` as `getIsActive`. In the props of the component there's one called `isActive`, it's extracted by using object destructuring AND renamed locally as `getIsActive`.

Parenthesis are required here as the jsx markup spans multiple lines. Had it been a single line jsx, no parenthesis would've been needed.

And yes, this is a function (component) that returns jsx markup. This is known as `stateless component` as it's just a simple function. The opposite would be a full-blown React component that extends `React.Component`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing in the function arguments is object destructuring. In react whenever you make a stateless component it has `props` passed in as an argument to the stateless function.
`isActive: getIsActive` is saying grab the property `isActive` from the `props` object and set it to a variable called `getIsActive` which is something you can do with object destructuring.
THe rest of it is just pulling the specific properties we want from the `props` object and turning them into their own variables. This is great for declaring what props a component is going to consume. `...rest`
will create a variable called `rest` which will be an object with the remaining properties that weren't declared previously.

you can find more information on Destructuring here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects into distinct
>   variables.

the parenthesis are there since the jsx spans multiple lines vs being on one line and since we are immediately returning and not doing any assignment in the function we don't need to use blocks around the function body.